# using url_launcher to send a message to Telegram from Flutter app

Tags: flutter, whatsapp, telegram-api, url-launcher

I have used this code to send a message to WhatsApp using flutter with url_launcher,

```
void sendCodeByWhatsApp({
    required int phone,
    required String message,
  }) async {
    String url() {
      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        return "whatsapp://send?phone=$phone&text=${Uri.parse(message)}";
      } else {
        return "https://wa.me/$phone?text=${Uri.parse(message)}";
      }
    }
    if (await canLaunchUrl(Uri.parse(url()))) {
      print("https://wa.me/$phone/?text=$message");
      await launchUrl(Uri.parse(url()));
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch ${url()}';
    }
  }
```

how can I edit it to send a message to the Telegram or viber for example?

Comment: for telegram you could try t.me/yourusername

Comment: it should be with phone number not username?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. https://telegram.me/905555555555 it works. I did not test all possibilities btw.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus

This opens up a wide range of option to send text from flutter app to another app.
More over the implementation is quite user friendly as well. For instance
Share.share('check out my website https://example.com');